# How do I enable line numbers (on the left) every time when line is the long logical line

Tags: line-numbers, wrapping

I have `linum-mode` enabled as well as `truncate-lines`.  Works fine as long as Emacs displays column 0:

[image]
The line number is  showed  on left (OK)

But as soon as the window is scrolled horizontally, the line numbers disappear:

[image]
The line number is not showed on left

How do I make it so the line numbers (on the left) stay displayed when I move along a long logical line ?

Comment: I think you're seeing a plain bug.  This affects both `linum-mode` and `nlinum-mode`, apparently.  I recommend you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: FYI: I don't observe this behaviour with Emacs 24.5.1 and linum-mode 0.9.24 on Linux, the line numbers remain visible.

Comment: I see the same problem, Emacs 25.0.93.1 on Windows. @user3875715 what version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: @ph0t0nix:  I do see this behavior on Emacs 24.5 on Linux.  Curious if you tried it with `emacs -Q`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. You are both right, I observe the same thing. I totally missed the part where the OP says column 0 shouldn't be visible for this to appear.

Comment: @glucas: I have tried  emacs on version 24.5,23.4,24.3(windows) and plugin  on nlinum-mode 1.6,   linum-mode0.9.24.

Comment: Is this still an issue on 25.1?

Comment: I see the same behaviour in my (fairly recent build from upstream) emacs: GNU Emacs 26.0.50.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.9) of 2017-02-07

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in linum-mode.

bug#24169: 
https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24169

Line numbers will indeed disappear with horizontal scrolling when using line-truncation. See reproduction details in bug report.